# P0456 if i can drive

Tags: dodge, journey

My car ignition light came on today and it said loose fuel cap and tighten or replace necessary and threw p0456 is it ok to drive this weekend and take it In Monday

Comment: Have you checked the fuel cap?

Comment: Yeah I tightened it

Comment: Hello just wondered

Comment: Have you driven it since tightening it - it may reset itself.

Comment: Yeah home after I went to get it checked it just came on today I was just wondering if be ok thru the weekend

Comment: Hello let me know

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can continue to drive without worry. This means you have a small leak in your EVAP system. This system is supposed to prevent gas fumes from escaping to the outside air. The most common place for a leak is from the gas cap. That is why the check has cap warning pops up. The first thing to do is to clean or preferably replace the gas cap. The warning light will not immediately turn off even if the problem is solved. It needs time to do a self test. Replace the gas cap and thoroughly clean the spout where the gas cap seals in and drive for a week or 2. If the light doesn't turn off in a couple of weeks, then there's probably a small leak in the system. That's when you would consider bringing it into the shop. If it turns off you've saved the time and money.

Comment: So It will be ok for the weekend

Comment: Hello jupiter.....

Comment: Cam I still put gas in it